# Want to validate date in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, date

I am trying to validate date in lwc. When i enter date as "0000-05-05" it show its not valid but when i enter date as "0005-05-05" it shows its valid date and apex class throws error for this. Can anyone have nay solution to validate the date if it have all the 4 digits for year, before it goes to apex class.

Does any change in regex solve it.

My code to validate date

```
dateIsValid(){
    const regex = /^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    return regex.test(this.signeddate);
}
```

Comment: check the following link, there are many different regex expressions based different date format requirements. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-formats-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mmm-yyyy

Comment: From the above pattern I am getting true for both the dates

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to figure this out.

```
const theDate = new Date(this.signeddate);
// Salesforce supports 1700-4000 AD/CE
if(isNaN(theDate) || theDate.getFullYear() < 1700 || theDate.getFullYear() > 4000) {
  // inform user of invalid date
}
```